# GMAIL SMTP Connect Fails On Server But Works On Local

Tags: php, linux, smtp, chilkat

I am using chilkat library to send email, it works perfectly on my local server/pc, but on live server it fails on smtp connect.

I tried both SSL and tls port.. (465/587) but both fails with same kind of error message..

following is the part of code to connect to google smtp server

```
//init
$smtp = new CkMailMan();
$smtp->put_VerboseLogging(true);
$smtp->put_SmtpHost('smtp.gmail.com');
$smtp->put_SmtpPort(465);
$smtp->put_SmtpSsl(true);
//connect
if(!$smtp->SmtpConnect())
{
    file_put_contents('./log/smtp_error_' . $GLOBALS['unixTime'] . '.log', $smtp->lastErrorXml());
    unset($smtp);
    echo '!failed!';
    exit();
}
```

and here is the log file:

```
  <ChilkatLog>
  <SmtpConnect ms="30066">
    <DllDate>Jun 25 2022</DllDate>
    <ChilkatVersion>9.5.0.91</ChilkatVersion>
    <UnlockPrefix>NONE</UnlockPrefix>
    <Architecture>Little Endian; 64-bit</Architecture>
    <Language>Linux PHP</Language>
    <VerboseLogging>1</VerboseLogging>
    <ensureSmtpConnection ms="30066">
      <smtpParams>
        <SmtpHost>smtp.gmail.com</SmtpHost>
        <SmtpPort>465</SmtpPort>
        <SmtpUsername></SmtpUsername>
        <SmtpSsl>1</SmtpSsl>
        <StartTLS>0</StartTLS>
      </smtpParams>
      <smtpConnect ms="30066">
        <smtpHostname>smtp.gmail.com</smtpHostname>
        <smtpPort>465</smtpPort>
        <connectionIsReady>
          <info>SMTP host changed.</info>
          <info>SMTP port changed.</info>
          <info>Need new SMTP connection, something changed!</info>
        </connectionIsReady>
        <smtpSocketConnect ms="30066">
          <socket2Connect ms="30066">
            <connect2 ms="30066">
              <hostname>smtp.gmail.com</hostname>
              <port>465</port>
              <ssl>True</ssl>
              <connectImplicitSsl ms="30066">
                <info>Clearing TLS client certificates.</info>
                <connectSocket ms="30066">
                  <domainOrIpAddress>smtp.gmail.com</domainOrIpAddress>
                  <port>465</port>
                  <connectTimeoutMs>30000</connectTimeoutMs>
                  <connect_ipv6_or_ipv4 ms="30066">
                    <info>Single-threaded domain to IP address resolution</info>
                    <info>connecting to IPV4 address...</info>
                    <ipAddress>172.253.115.108</ipAddress>
                    <createSocket>
                      <info>Setting SO_SNDBUF size</info>
                      <sendBufSize>262144</sendBufSize>
                      <info>Setting SO_RCVBUF size</info>
                      <recvBufSize>4194304</recvBufSize>
                    </createSocket>
                    <connect ms="30065">
                      <info>Waiting for the connect to complete...</info>
                      <connectTimeoutMs>30000</connectTimeoutMs>
                      <error>timeout waiting for connect to complete;</error>
                      <timeoutMs>30000</timeoutMs>
                      <failedWaitToConnect>Socket operation timeout.</failedWaitToConnect>
                    </connect>
                  </connect_ipv6_or_ipv4>
                </connectSocket>
                <error>pmConnect failed.</error>
              </connectImplicitSsl>
              <connectFailReason>6</connectFailReason>
              <ConnectFailReason>Timeout</ConnectFailReason>
              <error>A few possible causes for a connection timeout are:</error>
              <error>- The remote host is not reachable (perhaps a firewall is blocking the connection on the remote end).</error>
              <error>- Your ISP is blocking the outbound connection (this is common for SMTP port 25).</error>
              <error>- If your timeout is too short, then maybe the server is just too slow to accept the connection.</error>
            </connect2>
          </socket2Connect>
          <error>Failed to connect to SMTP server..</error>
        </smtpSocketConnect>
      </smtpConnect>
    </ensureSmtpConnection>
    <error>Failed.</error>
  </SmtpConnect>
</ChilkatLog>
```

i have consulted with server tech and they said, all the port 465,587,25 all is open.

so, i am so confused why it is not working?

info: it's linux server with plex

Comment: Double-check that you have provided the correct SMTP username and password for your Gmail account. An empty value for SmtpUsername in the log suggests that the username was not provided.

Comment: @James, sir, function "SmtpConnect" does not use user name and/or password, only "SmtpAuthenticate" uses user name and password, nevertheless, i have tried to set user name and password prior to "SmtpConnect" call, but it still produced same error log.

Comment: The error logs show clearly it is connection problem. (likely firewall problem ?)

Comment: @KenLee, dear sir, i also think so, but firewall is completely disabled, and also server tech confirmed that there is no issue to connection to google server and also those mentioned ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of what your server tech says, you should validate that the ports are open and eliminate at least one of the possibilities.

Here's a simple script that attempts to connect through various ports, and returns a SUCCESS or ERROR message for each.

```
<?php
$servers = array(
    array("ssl://www.google.com", 443),
    array("smtp.gmail.com", 465),
    array("smtp.gmail.com", 587),
);

foreach ($servers as $server) {
    list($server, $port) = $server;
    echo "<h1>Attempting connect to <tt>$server:$port</tt></h1>\n";
    flush();
    $socket = fsockopen($server, $port, $errno, $errstr, 10);
    if(!$socket) {
      echo "<p>ERROR: $server:$portsmtp - $errstr ($errno)</p>\n";
    } else {
      echo "<p>SUCCESS: $server:$port - ok</p>\n";
    }
    flush();
}
```